# Proving that every function defined on a discrete metric space is uniformly continuous.

Tags: general-topology

> Proving that every function defined on a discrete metric space is uniformly continuous.

I know that every function on compact set is uniformly continuous, but how about discrete metric space.  Can someone please gimme a hand on this please?

Comment: What are the open balls of radius $1/2$ in a discrete space?

Comment: This is misleading: what it should say is that any function from a discrete metric space to another discrete metric space is uniformly continuous. A function from a discrete metric space to an arbitrary metric space can be very far from uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: For any $\varepsilon>0$ put $\delta:=\dfrac12$ in the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: Actually can you explain a little bit finding the distance of the ball?

Comment: If $d(x,y)<\frac12$ then $x=y$, hence $|f(x)-f(y)|=0<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Ohhh duh ok hitting my head with a stick